# How can I iterate through Firebase table if it contains data from more app authenticated users?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a travel Android app and the idea is that a user can authenticate and create a personal account through Firebase Authentication. One of the functionalities says that every user can post reviews. Now, what I want is to retrieve all the reviews from the Firebase Realtime Database (not just the current user reviews, all of them). How could I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the reviews that correspond to all users, you have to iterate twice, like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference reviewsRef = rootRef.child("reviews");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot uidSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot reviewSnapshot : uidSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String comment = reviewSnapshot.child("comment").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", comment);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
reviewsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
Really nice place
The ideal place for holiday. No matter if it
Hi
```

If you are using a POJO class for your review object, then please use:

```
Review review = reviewSnapshot.getValue(Review.class);
Log.d("TAG", review.getComment());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved my problem! :)